# Favicon in TeX/PDF

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

I am creating a document in TeX (TeX Studio) and I use the Mozilla Firefox browser to view the generated PDF. Well, is there a package / function to add a favicon?

[image: Favicon in Browser]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. Favicons are not part of the PDF standard, so there is no way for LaTeX to provide that information to the browser. The browsers just take the favicon of the website the PDF resides on, if present.

The folks at Mozilla have been aware of this shortcoming for some time, though (see [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=960940) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=988686)). Their goal is to use a preview of the PDF itself as the favicon. They just need someone to implement it..

Comment: Ok, I'll contact mozilla firefox developers.